# How to make stack navigator header title dynamic while having nested tab navigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I wish to make the stack navigator header title dynamic while having nested tab navigators. Here is the code

```
// ProjectDetailNavigator is a screen in a stack navigator
const ProjectDetailNavigator = TabNavigator(
{
    Overview: { screen: ProjectOverview },
    Detail: { screen: ProjectDetail },
},
{
tabBarOptions: {
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    labelStyle: {
        color: 'black'
    },
}
});


    ProjectDetailNavigator.navigationOptions = {    
       title: 'Dynamic Project Title',
        header: {
           style: {
              elevation: 0,
              shadowOpacity: 0,
             }
         }
      };

      export default ProjectDetailNavigator;
```

Possible solution i have tried but to no avail is as follows

```
    ProjectDetailNavigator.navigationOptions = function ({navigation}) {
    return {    
    title: `${navigation.state.params.title}` ,
header: {
    style: {
        elevation: 0,
        shadowOpacity: 0,
           }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by nested tabs, from what i see you have an app containing a tabBar, do you want to have a title on navBar for each tab ? is this what your asking for ?

Comment: The tabBar is nested is nested under a stacknavigator whose title I want to make dynamic. Hence ProjectDetailNavigator is a screen in stack navigator

Answer (score 1):

Inside the component:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`
});
```

Comment: inside which component ? ProjectDetailNavigator

Comment: Inside ProjectOverview or ProjectDetail... where you want to display it. Or do you want to display it in the tabBarLabel?

Comment: the header i wish to make dynamic is that of ProjectDetailNavigator not the one for ProjectOverview or ProjectDetail or tabBarLabels